# Change HTML5 input validation error text based on localization and using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

For example this is the message you get if the you try to validate a required input :

> Please, fill in this field

Is it possible to change default input validation error message language using javascript without `setCustomValidity` function for each validation?

Comment: Considering this is by browser, I imagine the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially, I'm assuming by validation you mean you use something along the lines of "required" in the html.  This would normally bring up a message in the browser.

The other option would be to create your own javascript function to verify and validate the form input.  From this validation function, you could insert your own language libraries here, and control the message output.

Here is a non-tested seudo code example:

```
<form onSubmit="validate()">
    <label for="thing1">Input Here</label>
    <input id="thing1" type="textbox"/>
</form>
```

Included Javascript:

```
function validate() {
    //Do validation, and output a popup window or something similar 
    //with your custom message on error.
}
```

For reference, a quick google search returned this jquery library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-lang-js